# Compiling and executing flex (scanner generator)

Tags: compilation, flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

I am trying to understand how to generate scanner generator using flex.
Let's say I successfully write my flex file. I have txt file which will be treated as input file. I want this file to be modified by deleting some patterns which are defined in flex file. I was able to:

1. flex `myscanner.l` in terminal
2. I got my `flex.yy.c` file
3. Then `gcc -Wall -c lex.yy.c` (2 warnings) Created `lex.yy.o`
4. Now I don’t know how to create my a.out file and create my new file after going through scanner which will do changes in the original.(yyout?)

I would be grateful for helping me finish this.

Comment: I think tag flex is not correct (flex is used for Apache flex)

Comment: thanks you, i changed it.

Comment: Are you saying that gcc did not create a.out even though it reported no errors?

Comment: @Dago: remove `-c` from the command line, then. Do you have a `main` function defined in your flex file? If not, you'll need one. (PD: Flex is not a substitute for C programming. You need to know the basics of C in order to use flex.)

Comment: I managed to succesfully compile it after adding c code. I used in flex %option noyywrap option. In manual it says i can link -lfl library. Can u tell me where and how to do it in terminal?